# sorting dataframe by one factor column ascending another factor descending

Tags: r, sorting

I have a dataframe which is consisted by two factor column.
And I want to sort it by one column ascending and another descending.
More specifically, I want to find equivalent R code to SQL
"order by 1 asc, 2 desc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the `order` function with `method = "radix"` which allows you to pass a vector for the argument `decreasing`:

```
## Generate sample data:
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(a = letters[sample(1:5, 20, replace = TRUE)], 
    b = rep(c("orange", "apple", "pear", "banana"), 5))
## Sort by increasing a and decreasing b:
dat2 <- dat[order(dat$a, dat$b, decreasing = c(FALSE, TRUE), method = "radix"),]

head(dat2)
   a      b
15 a   pear
6  a  apple
18 a  apple
19 b   pear
1  b orange
17 b orange
```

Alternatively you could sort both columns in increasing order and just reverse column `b` using the function `rev`:

```
dat3 <- dat[order(dat$a, rev(dat$b)),]

head(dat3)
   a      b
15 a   pear
6  a  apple
18 a  apple
19 b   pear
1  b orange
17 b orange
```

Comment: I just found this method is not working. Just your sample's column b is not ordered decreasing.

Comment: The sorting gives priority to column a. For duplicate values of a, column b is sorted in a decreasing order. You cannot generally sort a data frame so that two columns are in a specified order.

Answer (score 0):

You can arrange rows by variables easily with `dplyr::arrange`

Example:

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(a= letters[sample(1:26, 20)], 
        b = rep(c("orange", "apple", "pear", "banana"), 5))
dat %>% arrange(a, desc(b))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,however, is there another way using base package?

Comment: Check this instead... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns